# How does one install torchmeta using conda?

Tags: pytorch, conda

I wanted to install torchmeta with conda because it's giving me some other isses as here: [How does one install torchmeta for a ppc64le architecture in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049603/how-does-one-install-torchmeta-for-a-ppc64le-architecture-in-pytorch)

so I hope by removing the pip variable I have less things that might be causing my errors...

---

related:

- https://github.com/tristandeleu/pytorch-meta/issues/63

Comment: So what, precisely, have you tried so far and what error(s) are you getting?